# End point URL of a web service deployed in websphere application server

Tags: web-services, websphere-7

I have deployed a web service in websphere application server v7.0.

Is it possible to see the end point URL of the web service in the Websphere application server itself?

If yes, where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Inside WAS admin console navigate to:
Appplications>Enterprise Applications>{web_service_application}>Provide HTTP endpoint URL information